# Firebase, insecure rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I recently received an email from firebase telling me that the rules of my database (Firestore) are insecure so I changed them to the following:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match / databases / {database} / documents {
    match / {document = **} {
     allow read: if true;
    allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Before I had these rules:

```
allow read, write: if true;
```

After making the change, the emails keep coming back and I don't know what else to do.
I already tried several of the following options given in this link but none of them works for what I need.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/insecure-rules#firestore

I need authenified users to be able to read and create content. So use the rules that I put above.

I saw that in the email they send me it says that people can modify my database, is this referring to from the app, or does it mean that they can hack me or something?

Because the end of my app is that users can create content.

But I don't want someone to hack into my database and delete everything, is that possible?

[image: Data Base]

Thanks

Comment: Can you share what your database structure looks like and which users can edit documents? Should the users be able to write any document as mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Yes, users must be able to create content, the only thing I want to know is that if I use these rules does it mean that someone can hack me or something?

Comment: And my database is from Firestore and there are two collections, one with Users and the other with Posts, where the posts of all users are added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emails are because the rules aren't really stringent. You should probably be using the following rule, that:

1. **Allows unauthenticate users to read data**
2. **Allows authenticated users to create entries**
3. **Allows to update & delete entries that are only owned by themselves and not of others.**

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow public read access, but only content owners can write
    match /some_collection/{document} {
      allow read: if true
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author_uid;
      allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.author_uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Read this [article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics) for better understanding. You can also check when `firestore` flags rules as insecure over [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/insecure-rules). More importantly, this is the point to be emphasized.

> Remember that Firebase allows clients direct access to your data, and
> Firebase Security Rules are the only safeguard blocking access for
> malicious users. Defining rules separately from product logic has a
> number of advantages: clients aren't responsible for enforcing
> security, buggy implementations will not compromise your data, and
> most importantly, you're not relying on an intermediary server to
> protect data from the world.

**Sample rules**:

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userDoc} {
      allow read: if true
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.id;
      allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.id;
    }

    match /posts/{postDoc} {
      allow read: if true
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.user_id;
    }

    match /comments/{commentDoc} {
      allow read: if true
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.user_id;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But if I want all users to be able to create content, as in intsgram. How do I do it? Because in the example you give me, they can only create if he is the author but in my app people can comment on other posts from other users.

Comment: Well in that case you should have `posts` and `comments` as two separate collections. So when someone comments on a post, that comment entry will be created in the `comments` collection and only that will owned by the person who created it. Naturally, only the person who created that comment will be able to update or delete the comment. But, he will not be able to modify or delete the entire post from the `posts` collection. Did you get me?

Comment: The above example is correct. It all depends on how you structure your database.

Comment: Yep! You need to make sure that only the owner gets to modify the entries whereas the read access is granted to all. So keeping this in mind you should structure your database.

Comment: Ok thanks, But having insecure rules does not mean that I can be hacked, does it?

Comment: I already added an image where you can see how my post collection is. And another thing, in my app I use the uid to make sure that only the creator of the post modifies it, and I have not had any problem in the database.

Comment: replying to your previous comment about being hacked. What we mean is, that people can modify your db without your consent that may cause unexpected behavior in your app. So it makes sense to allow people to modify the resources that only they own. So technically, it won't classify has hacking, but rather hijacking, if that makes sense. Because keeping insecure rules is like keeping the door open for all sorts of tricks. So Google says that they have provided all sorts of security, but if you don't make use of the security, then you are probably getting hijacked.

Comment: Ok thanks, the problem I have is that in my database I have several collections in which a user can add content, so I don't see why to use this more sophisticated rule if the idea of the app is that the user share information.

Comment: Because I tried to use the above rules but when I put the users collection, it only let the user modify the users collection but not the posts collection.

Comment: Well no matter how many collections you have, the idea is to maintain the user_id against each entry in each collection. It can be in `posts`, `comments` or any other collection. So when you try to update or delete you just validate the `request.auth.id` against the entry's user_id, by using `request.resource.data.user_id`. So with this all users can create content, but modifications can only be done if they own the entry. Clear now?

Comment: @Unpocodetodos I've attached sample rules in my answer to give you a better idea of how rules should be specified. Ideally, please specify rules for each collection rather than having one generic rule for all collections.

Answer (score 0):

This case is mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/insecure-rules#open_access). Any authenticated user can write to your database and that also involves deleting data. You are using a recursive wildcard which gives them access to complete database.

Instead try rules that allow users to write their own documents only or something similar.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match / databases / {database} / documents {
    match /collectionName/{docId} {
     allow read: if true;
    allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == docId;
    }
  }
}
```

Above example will allow users to edit documents where document ID is equal to their UID only.

If you wish to allow selected users to write (such as admin) then you can add a field namely admin and set it to true in user's document in users collection. Then you can read the document data as shown:

```
match /collection/{document} {
      allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true;
      allow read: true;
    }
```

Comment: But if I want all users to be able to create content, as in intsgram. How do I do it?

And when they say "access to complete database", do they mean that they can hack me?